# MDX Code much slower than MDX Browser

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, cube, bids

When I browse my Cube and drag/drop different elements for calculations I get my results within a second or two. However, my MDX code (created by the Wizard) takes around 6 minutes or so.. let's say I have 10 instances of what I drag/drop for calculation, even so, it should not take more than 10 seconds.. let alone 6 minutues!! thank you so much for your help.

Comment: can you add some code for each scenario

Answer (score 0):

Browser creates an unoptimized code in the background. To have a look at the code generated by the browser, click on the "Design Mode" icon.

[image]

You will often see the code riddled with number of subcubes, which might seem non-intuitive and ineficient coding practices.

As far as I know, there is no way to control this code. Deal with it! And use MDX to query your cube's data.

Comment: Subcubes are not so so inefficient Sourav - usually the difference between a sub-cube and a where clause is not much.

Comment: No no. I didn't mean that at all. My point was inefficient code. That's not to say subcubes are inefficient, just to give an idea how the generated code looks like.

Comment: To be honest Sourav the main problem is another vague question posted by `LearnByReading`. We want specific `mdx` posts that get into the nitty gritty of the language - this post just has too many possible answers.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti thanks for the answer. The problem is somewhat opposite though: the browser runs quickly but the report that the wizard creates is rather slow. But this somewhat helps so that I can see what code is used in the browser.

Comment: What's the query that's taking time? Edit the question and paste it pls.